# mongoose fetch only certain fields in callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

how can i get in callback only the socketId field instead of all document model?

```
   User.findByIdAndUpdate(
            socket.handshake.session.user.id,
            { $set: { 'socketId': socket.id } },
            {safe: true, upsert: true , new:true},
            function(err, model) {

                if(err){

                console.log('Error');

                }
                if(!model){

                console.log('No User');
                }

                if(model){
                console.log(model);
                }
            });
```

Comment: By adding `fields` to the same options document where `upsert` and `true` are declared. `safe` is kind of deprecated, so it looks like you are following someones blog example rather than [documentation.](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)

Comment: the fields work, but i still having the _id on model.

Comment: `fields: '-_id +socketId'` Or `fields: { "_id": 0, "socketId": 1 }` Whichever makes the most sense to you. Note the only field you are allowed to "exclude" along with an explicit "include" is the `_id` field. Trying to explicitly "exlude" other fields produces an error. So you either just "exclude" what you do not want or "include" all the fields you want. That is with regards to anything but `_id`.

Comment: thanks, i have read the documentation before but i didn't  understand well, you make it more clear.